# Check if input fields are filled out in a form

Tags: javascript

I have a form `myForm` and I want to check if specific input field are filled out before sending the form. I'm very new to JavaScript so I don't really know what I did wrong. Any help is welcomed.

```
function validateForm() {
    var validate = true;
    var alert_string = "";
    var children = $("#myForm").children("input");
    console.log(children.size());
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length ; i++){
        if(children[i].attr(id).substring(0,8) != "ABC_FLAT"){
            if(children[i].attr(id) == null || children[i].attr(id) == ""){
                validate = false;
                alert_string = alert_string.concat(childrern[i].attr(id)).concat(", ");
            }
        }
    }
    alert_string = alert_string.concat("must be filled out !");
    if(validate == false){
        alert(alert_string);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Add log outputs to find out where the problem occurs.

Comment: try it by yourself : on submit event of form loop through all children input tags and check if value is entered or not. if not then prevent event from firing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
children[i].attr(id) == ""   // wrong
```

You don't have to check whether their `id`s are null, you have to check whether their **value**s are empty :)

```
if(children[i].value == "")
```

Since you are already using jQuery, you can simplify that code to a great extent. For example a simple "all fields filled" check can be

```
var flag=0;
$('#myForm').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === '' )
         flag=1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you'll use jQuery, you can check the input fields if empty AND trap also white space/s. Add a class to all input fields , e.g. class="required" and add attribute fieldname with respective value for each input field.

```
     var requiredFields = "";
        $("#myForm").find('.required').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
                requiredFields += " - " + $(this).attr("fieldname") + "\n";
            }
        });

        if (requiredFields != "") {
            alert("Please enter the following required field(s): \n" + requiredFields);
        } else {
            //save here
        }
```

Comment: I would prefer you add some explanation to your code.. why it will work / fix the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `required` like `<input required type="text" name="email" id="log" />` or use jQuery like

```
$("form").submit(function() { 
    var has_empty = false;
    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
        if(! $(this).val()) {
            has_empty = true; 
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(has_empty){return false;}
});
```